# problem not showing edit form after uploading document

Tags: file-upload, edit

in my document library I have some custom fields so when I use dialog box to upload documents after uploading when page is try to redirect to edit form I get error file not found. in log I get "Failed to cache field with id" for 4 id.
I use SharePoint manager to find fields:

1. I couldn't find one of the field.
2. field type is lookup with picker (custom field I love SharePoint)
3. Simple lookup field that I use for cascading
4. cascading lookup

because of this errors I used to use Link new item full page (not in dialog box) suddenly it stop working from yesterday.
I want to have edit form in order to fill required fields.
in this past days I did not add any fields , I may just edit default view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take SharePoint Designer...Open your List where Edit Form is corrupted--> There is option to create new **edit form**--> Click on the button to create new edit form and then make it as **default**. Now check if you are getting all the fields when clicking in Edit option.

Comment: I have test your answer but It didn't solve it .

Comment: Are you able to create new Edit form?